# Making a Sequence from an Iterator

Tags: raku

I'm trying to make an iterator, then build a sequence from it, but it doesn't act the way I think it should.  What's up?

Here's my basic class:

```
class Foo {
    has $.x = 0;
    has $.max = 3;

    method val() {
        (++$!x > $!max) ?? () !! ($!x, "string $!x")
    }
}

my $foo = Foo.new;
say $foo.val.perl for ^4;

# (1, "string 1")
# (2, "string 2")
# (3, "string 3")
# ()
```

It just iterates until max, then returns (), works the way I think it should.

Then I build an Iterator from that, just a single `pull-one()` method.

```
class Foo-Iterator does Iterator {
    has Foo $.foo;

    method pull-one() {
        $!foo.val || IterationEnd
    }
}

my $iter = Foo-Iterator.new(foo => Foo.new);
$iter.pull-one.perl.say for ^4;

# (1, "string 1")
# (2, "string 2")
# (3, "string 3")
# IterationEnd
```

It still acts the way I expect it to.

If I access it with a Seq, it still works fine:

```
.perl.say for Seq.new: Foo-Iterator.new(foo => Foo.new);
# (1, "string 1")
# (2, "string 2")
# (3, "string 3")
```

That is still what I expect to see, the same thing the Iterator returned.

Finally, I store the Seq in an `@` variable and print the results of that:

```
my @seq = Seq.new: Foo-Iterator.new(foo => Foo.new);
.perl.say for @seq;
# $(4, "string 1")
# $(4, "string 2")
# $(4, "string 3")
```

What's up with that? It is seems to be using the later value of the variable rather than the value it had at the time of the pull-one call() (which the string forces to be a value).  Does a `Seq` return it as a container rather than a value?  Is this laziness in action, where it doesn't pull until requested so it gets a later value?

If I make `val()` return `+$!x` instead of returning `$!x`, it seems to grab the value and give me what I want, I'm just trying to understand the behavior I see.

Comment: This is Rakudo version 2018.11 built on MoarVM version 2018.11
implementing Perl 6.d.

Comment: It also works the way I think it should if I use a `$` variable to store the Seq, then iterate with `for @$seq`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made precisely 4 changes to `Foo`: `does Iterator`, `pull-one`, `IterationEnd`, and I decont `%!x` with `<>`.

Your method was passing the container for `$!x` when you really want to pass the value inside of the container, so it needed `$!x<>`.
The reason you didn't notice it with the rest of the code is that the array assignment was the only one that was `eager`.

I did the rest of the changes because it already has state, and it only works once. Which is exactly how an `Iterator` should work. With your code it makes zero sense to add another object for an `Iterator` that basically only renames a method.

```perl6
class Foo does Iterator {
    #     ^-----------^
    has $.x = 0;
    has $.max = 3;

    method pull-one() {
        #  ^------^

        (++$!x > $!max) ?? IterationEnd !! ($!x<>, "string $!x")
        #                  ^----------^        ^^
    }
}
```

Now to use it

```perl6
my $seq = Seq.new( Foo.new );

for $seq<> { .say }
# (1 string 1)
# (2 string 2)
# (3 string 3)

my @seq = Seq.new( Foo.new );
for @seq { .say }
# (1 string 1)
# (2 string 2)
# (3 string 3)
```

---

Assuming that your example is entirely too simple, and there is a good reason for having a separate `Iterator`, why do you have a mutating `val` method?

```perl6
class Foo-Iterator {…}

class Foo does Iterable {
    has $.max = 3;

    method val ( $index ) {
        ($index > $!max) ?? () !! ($index, "string $index")
    }

    method iterator (){
        # pass `self` for method calls or such
        # (could pass internal data additionally/instead)
        Foo-Iterator.new( :foo(self) )
    }
}

class Foo-Iterator does Iterator {
    # the mutating value
    has $!x = 0;

    # make it public only so we don't have
    # to mess with `new` or `BUILD`
    has $.foo is required;

    # only have the mutating logic in this object
    method pull-one() {
        $!foo.val( ++$!x ) || IterationEnd
    }
}
```

Now to use it.

```perl6
# only one Foo object needed
my $foo = Foo.new;

# for Seq.new($foo.iterator) { .say }
for $foo<> { .say }
# (1 string 1)
# (2 string 2)
# (3 string 3)

for $foo<> { .say }
# (1 string 1)
# (2 string 2)
# (3 string 3)

my $iter-a = $foo.iterator;
my $iter-b = $foo.iterator;

say $iter-a.pull-one;
# (1 string 1)
say $iter-a.pull-one;
# (2 string 2)
say $iter-b.pull-one; # notice that $iter-b isn't tied to $iter-a
# (1 string 1)

my @seq = $foo<>;
for @seq { .say }
# (1 string 1)
# (2 string 2)
# (3 string 3)
```